# Android studio quit unexpectedly on Mac Catalina beta

Tags: macos, android-studio, macos-catalina

I installed the latest version of Mac OS (Catalina Beta 10.15) and faced with the following problem: when I open Android studio and start writing code studio quits with [such crash report](https://pastebin.com/Tn7Ah7Gp). Can you help me to solve this problem, as it really doesn't allow to work normally. I think that re-installing can help, but maybe there are any other solutions?

```
*Message in a code style, because pastebin links require that *
```

Comment: A bug in macOS, or an incompatibility between Android Sutdio and/or the Java JRE and the macOS release. Isn't something like this to be expected with beta software? I recommend you downgrade your Mac to a productive macOS version.

Comment: @Codo, yes, but it's a bit strange that there are almost no similar questions. So, I thought that it is the problem with my pc

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a know problem in several JetBrains based products.

As a workaround, add `-Dsun.font.layoutengine=icu` into Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart IDE.

Also see: [Unexpected crash when I update my MacBook Pro to MacOS Version 10.15 Beta (19A501i)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1639)

Comment: You can update the vmoptions in /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions. Thanks! saved my day.

Comment: o thank you so much, you saved my life, the company was about to fire me :)))

Comment: Thank you bro, I have the same problem but this worked for me. big thanks

Comment: Didn't work on my Mac with macOS 10.14.5. :-(  Regular IntelliJ works just fine, Android Studio crashes with the same options that work for IntelliJ. Go figure...

Comment: Men, you save my day.  Android Studio 4.1. Mac OS Big Sur  (date 05.11.2020)

Comment: Seems to have worked for me too, fingers crossed