# Why do Android Studio and Android Virtual Device Manager crash immediately when I try to create emulator?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-device-manager

I have been unable to create a virtual device in using the AVD Manager in Android studio. I am using MacOS Catalina 10.15.3, everything is updated, and I recently [completely uninstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac) and then reinstalled Android Studio.

Regardless of which device I select, when I click the "Next" button on the on the Select Hardware Screen, Android Studio crashes without creating the device.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's what I do:

I open the AVD Manager
[image: I open the AVD Manager]

I click "Create Virtual Device"
[image: I click Create Virtual Device]

I select any device and click the "Next" button
[image: I select any device and click the "Next" button]

Android Studio and Android Virtual Device Manager crash immediately
[image: Android Studio and Android Virtual Device Manager crash immediately]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you checked links like this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899994/android-studio-quit-unexpectedly-on-mac-catalina-beta?rq=1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880984/android-studio-quits-unexpectedly-on-mac

Comment: After trying everything else I could find, what eventually worked was to factory reset my mac and reinstall everything.

Comment: for a programmer always this way is last choice :))